# Get the actual object from QGraphicsItem Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, class, oop, object

My code successfully returns a `QList<QGraphicsItem *>` upon calling `items(event->pos())` in a mouse event. The code looks like this:

```
QList<QGraphicsItem *> itemsList = items(event->pos());
qDebug() << itemsList;
```

The debug output for a mouse event where there are two objects on top of each other:

```
(QGraphicsItem(this =0x10ab8c900, parent =0x0, pos =QPointF(180, 0) , z = 0 , flags =  ( ) ) ,  
 QGraphicsItem (this = 0x10159a800 , parent = 0x0 , pos = QPointF(180, 0) , z = 0 , flags =  ( ) ) )
```

That is perfectly fine to get the position etc., but is there a way to get the actual object instance? I see the `this` parameter with a memory address, so I guess I know the memory location. But how would I map that to an object?

I know that the latter QGraphicsItem instance is of type `Treasure *`, I tried some methods after getting it from the list, but nothing seems to do the trick. Is this even possible?

Comment: It is an object with a memory location that you can retrieve by this. What would you want to do with the object?

Comment: I want to call its getter method to get a private variable. How would I retrieve the object?

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what you mean. Objects are stored in memory locations. You can have a local object, or a pointer to an object stored in a different location. You could create a local object by copying the object you have. However there is no difference in what you're allowed to do with a local object. And what you're allowed to with an object accesed by through structural derefence (->).

Comment: @laurisvr I think we're on the same page. I want to copy the object I have in the `this` parameter of the QGraphicsItem. Could you please instruct me on how to do that?

Comment: That's a good question. If I were you I would just store all my pointers to my objects models added to the scene in a sort of list where you know the type of the object added. And simply loop throw itemsList to compare pointers in itemsList and in my modelList.

Comment: @Martin yes, I'll do that. I just wondered if there was another way. But how do I extract the pointer from the QGraphicsItem? varName->this obviously doesn't work..

Comment: itemsList->at(i) returns a pointer to QGraphicsItem

Comment: @Martin nevermind, I'll do it with the list.

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

The problem is your function returns a list of QGrapihcsItem *. Whereas you need instances of Treasure *. Since Treasure inherits QGraphicsItem you can apply downcasting in this occasion. This would look like this:

```
QGraphicsItem * result;
Treasure* myTreasure = dynamic_cast<Treasure>(result); 
if(myTreasure)
{
    //only do something if the cast is a succes
}
```

### Original

From the conversation under your question I gathered you want to copy you object. Say you would like to copy the at an index given in `i`. This would be the way of achieving this:

```
int i = 0;
Treasure myTreasure(*itemsList[index]);
```

This behaviour can however be disabled by the type. It would then still be possible to make a trivial copy like this:

```
Treasure myTreasure;
memcpy(&myTreasure, itemList[index], sizeof(Treasure);
```

However I would strongly advise not to this. Since this probably is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

P.S. I would once more like to mention that the only case in which you usually copy an object is if you want to keep it for local use. That is, you want to change it, such that the changes aren't reflected in the original instance. Or you want to keep the state the object is in, and don't want changes to the original to affect yours.

For almost all other purposes, accessing an object through a pointer is just as powerfull and usefull, if not more so, as making a copy.

Comment: The problem here is not really a copy of something, the problem is itemLists return a list of pointers to QGraphicsItem and in the scene, there are different types of QGraphicsItem. So the main problem is to know which type is the pointer you get.

Comment: @Martin Aah I see. That makes sense. I'm afraid the only solution to that in general is trying different downcasts. Which is an aspect of qt that is quite capable of bringing me to the verge of tears

Comment: Yeah, i tried things like this in the past and now, I'm trying to follow this logic. I always store somewhere the Model I want to display with a View. If thanks to a random View event, If I need the Model associated with the View, I just use the View to give me one sufficient information to find the right Model in my store Models (like an ID, an address, etc...). I rarely use the view to give me directly my Model. I don't know if it's really understandable.